# How to keep text selected when using number input to change fontSize

Tags: javascript, html, richtextbox, contenteditable

I'm trying to create a small richtexteditor by using `contenteditable` on a Div element but i've encountered a problem:

I want to be able to change the `fontSize`
of the current selection but when I use a number input field I lose the current selection so `document.execCommand('fontSize,false,myNumberValue)` does not work. Using `<button>` elements to execute the command does work but i'd rather use the number field, what are my options guys?

Comment: You can save the range (selected text), and then after then keep resetting the range over the text whenever you need.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run (am running) into this problem as well. It's a pain but I've simply found no way around it other than to save/restore the selection like Erik mentioned.

One possible way around it is to put the input inside of a modal so it greys out the contenteditable area but even then it's still just a work around. Just helps out the UX.

Here's a small snippet that I've used for doing something very similar.

```
saveSelection : function(){
    var sel = window.getSelection(), ranges = [];
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
            ranges.push(sel.getRangeAt(i));
        }
    }
    return ranges;
},
restoreSelection : function(savedSel){
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    for (var i = 0, len = savedSel.length; i < len; ++i) {
        sel.addRange(savedSel[i]);
    }
}
```

This seems to work in most modern browsers for me (Chrome, Safari, IE9+) but if you need it to support older browsers you may need to look into Rangy - https://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Comment: Ah that's a good idea I hadn't thought of it yet, works well. Thanks :)